# npm cache clean --force not cleaning the directory

Tags: npm, caching

I am facing the issue that my build server runs out of disk space after a period of time due to the size of npms `_cacache` folder.

After running `npm cache clean --force` and `npm cache verify`, the directory has the same size. The folders `content-v2` and `index-v5` are still full of files.

Can I manually delete the whole _cacache folder or is that going to cause any problems? Or am I missing something else?